# python: find keys in a dictionary whose values are lists of strings by searching list with a regex return an iterator over the keys

Tags: python, regex, dictionary, iterator

I have a dictionary whose items a lists of strings.  I want an iterator over the keys that gives me just those keys that have in their items a string which matches a regex.

```
my_dict = { "uk" : ["prince albert", "princes diana", "elton john", "john lennon"],
  "us" : ["albert einstein", "prince", "john cage", "president bush"],
  "germany" : ["otto von bismark", "prince karl", "goethe"],
  "netherlands" : ["albert durer", "rembrandt"]
}
```

my_dict.iterkeys() gives me an iterator with "uk", "us", "germany", "netherlands" (poosibly not in that order, I don't care).  This is what the code currently uses.

I want my_dict.iterkeysregex("prince") to give me an iterator with "uk", "us", "germany" and my_dict.iterkeysregex("albert") to give me "uk", "us", "netherlands".

How to write that function?

```
def iterkeysregex ...
```

Note, both my dict and the lists of items per key are small, so I'm not particularly worried about efficiency, e.g. O(num keys * num items per key * regex match time per item) would be just fine (two loops and a match call).  It's just that python isn't my first language and so I'm not certain I would get the syntax right.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
text = 'prince'
keys = set([key for key in my_dict for item in my_dict[key] if text in item])
```

or as a function:

```
def trick(text, values):
    keys = set([key for key in values for item in my_dict[key] if text in item])
    return keys
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is generator:

```
def iterkeysregex(regexp, dict):
  cr = re.compile(regexp)
  # index keys
  match_keys = [k for k, v in dict.items() if cr.search("".join(v))]
  # generating
  for k in match_keys:
    yield k
```

Usage

```
for x in iterkeysregex('to', my_dict):
  print(x, " --> ", my_dict[x])
```

Result:

```
uk  -->  ['prince albert', 'princes diana', 'elton john', 'john lennon']
germany  -->  ['otto von bismark', 'prince karl', 'goethe']
```

Answer (score 0):

The version I ended up using looks essentially like this:

```
def iterkeysregex(my_dict, my_regex):
    regex = re.compile(my_regex)
    for k, v in my_dict.iteritems():
      for s in v:
        if re.search(regex, s):
          yield k
```

Thanks to all who helped.